# How to measure performance for ABE Schemes

Tags: performance, abe

I have these 3 Schemes:

1) *J. Bethencourt, A. Sahai, and B. Waters*, "Ciphertext-policy attribute-based encryption"

2) *F. Guo, Y. Mu, W. Susilo, D. Wong, and V. Varadharajan*, "Cp-abe
with constant-size keys for lightweight devices"

3) *L. Ibraimi, M. Petkovic, S. Nikova, P. Hartel, and W. Jonker*, "Ciphertext-policy attribute-based threshold decryption with flexible delegation and revocation of user attributes"

How can i measure the **performance** of a scheme in a network ? (i.e scalability, number of users (producers and consumers) supported, number of contents supported) ? How can i make the performance **graphs** and **charts** of a scheme ? Are there tools and tutorials ?

Comment: You would have to implement the schemes you're interested in, but most metrics that you've listed are not implementation relevant. *Number of users or contents* is usually unbounded and may only be relevant for an application of a scheme and not the scheme itself. Can you expand on what you mean? How do you define *scalability*? I understand size of ciphertext and public key as well as speed of encryption, decryption and keygen as a useful performance metrics. If you want those then these are usually given as formulas based on group operations and group element sizes.

Comment: Ok I understand. I have an implementation of a first scheme in python. If you see this article (https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/1002.pdf), you can view a testbed. How can i reproduce these graphs and these test ? If I have formulas (Length of Decryption Key, Length of Ciphertext), how can i measure performance of a scheme (now i don't  have formulas to calculate speed of encrypt, decrypt and keygen, but i wish to have these) with these formulas ?

Comment: These graphs make only sense by applying IBE and ABE to the use case of a *network audit log*, which I am not familiar with. This isn't clear from your question that you want to do exactly that. If you're trying to determine various performance metrics for a specific use case, then you have to implement those schemes and your application, let it run and collect measurements.

Comment: I understand. No, i want measure performances of these schemes in a general case (not specific) to compare these. After i want to compare these and select which is the best.